# Task Status always WaitForActivation using .NET Core

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, .net-core, task

I know that the question has probably been asked several times but none of the solutions proposed work.

Basically, I have a .NET Core Solution that I want to use for implementing Identity Core. I have 3 projects in it

- Api project to handle the requests (Web Api)
- Core project for all the business logic (Class Library)
- Dal project for communication with the DB (Class Library)

All the setup is done properly, I have my DB created and the inital seed is done. My issue is that I cannot log in as in my LoginService the tasks are always WaitForActivation. My understanding of it is that there is a deadlock somewhere in my code but I cannot manage to find it.

**Code for the LoginController**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILoginService _loginService;

    public LoginController(ILoginService loginService)
    {
        _loginService = loginService;
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginDto login)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest("Email or password missing");

        var loginModel = Map(login);

        var result = await _loginService.SignInAsync(loginModel);

        return Ok();
    }

    private static LoginModel Map(LoginDto loginDto)
    {
        return new LoginModel
        {
            Email = loginDto.Email,
            Password = loginDto.Password,
            IsPersistent = loginDto.RememberMe
        };
    }
}
```

**Interface of the LoginService**

```
public interface ILoginService
{
    Task<SignInResult> SignInAsync(LoginModel model);
}
```

**Implementation of the interface LoginService**

```
public class LoginService : SignInManager<User>, ILoginService
{
    public LoginService(UserManager<User> userManager,
        IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor,
        IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<User> claimsFactory,
        IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor,
        ILogger<SignInManager<User>> logger,
        IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes)
        : base(userManager, contextAccessor, claimsFactory, optionsAccessor, logger, schemes)
    {
    }

    public async Task<SignInResult> SignInAsync(LoginModel model)
    {
        var result = await PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.IsPersistent, true);

        return result;
    }
}
```

**My Startup Class**

```
public class Startup
{
    private const string CORS_POLICY_NAME = "CORS";

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityServerConnectionString");
        services.AddDbContext<IdentityServerDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
            options.UseOpenIddict();
        });

        ConfigureCors(services);

        services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(o =>
            {
                o.Password.RequireDigit = true;
                o.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
                o.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
                o.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
                o.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
                o.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 3;
                o.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
                o.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityServerDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        // Register the OpenIddict services.
        services.AddOpenIddict()
            .AddCore(options =>
            {
                // Configure OpenIddict to use the Entity Framework Core stores and entities.
                options.UseEntityFrameworkCore()
                    .UseDbContext<IdentityServerDbContext>();
            })

            .AddServer(options =>
            {
                // Register the ASP.NET Core MVC binder used by OpenIddict.
                // Note: if you don't call this method, you won't be able to
                // bind OpenIdConnectRequest or OpenIdConnectResponse parameters.
                options.UseMvc();

                // Enable the token endpoint (required to use the password flow).
                options.EnableTokenEndpoint("/connect/token");

                // Allow client applications to use the grant_type=password flow.
                options.AllowPasswordFlow();

                // During development, you can disable the HTTPS requirement.
                options.DisableHttpsRequirement();

                // Accept token requests that don't specify a client_id.
                options.AcceptAnonymousClients();
            })

            .AddValidation();

        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.AddService(typeof(GlobalExceptionFilterAttribute));
            options.Filters.Add(new CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory(CORS_POLICY_NAME));
        });

        services.AddSingleton<GlobalExceptionFilterAttribute>();


        services.AddScoped<ILoginService, LoginService>();
        services.AddScoped<UserManager<User>>();
        services.AddScoped<UserStore<User>>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseCors(CORS_POLICY_NAME);
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc();

        SeedData.Initialize(serviceProvider);
    }

    private void ConfigureCors(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(CORS_POLICY_NAME, policy =>
            {
                policy.AllowAnyHeader();
                policy.AllowAnyMethod();
                policy.AllowAnyOrigin();

                if (Convert.ToBoolean(Configuration["AccessControlSettings:AllowCredentials"]))
                {
                    policy.AllowCredentials();
                }
                else
                {
                    policy.DisallowCredentials();
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

I hope this gives enough information to find a solution.

Comment: What does your `PasswordSignInAsync` implementation look like?

Comment: This is not my implementation, it is a method of Identity implemented in SignInManager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation I finally found what was my issue. There is nothing wrong with the code. The issue came from the user. I looked in the database and the securityStamp was NULL for the created user which seems to be problematic for identity

For people who would be interested in my reasoning process here it is. I was pretty sure that an exception would occur at some point behind the scene and it would havec helped me a lot to be able to have access to the stack trace. I have then changed the code a bit to be able to catch the exception I was interested in

```
try
        {
            var result = await Task.Run(() => _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(userName, password, isPersistent, true));

            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
```

That achived the stack trace was self explanatory and it was easy to find the solution. I hope it helped for anybody experiencing the same issue :)